# last participant support extension websphere

Tags: websphere, jython

Is there any jython script available to set Accept Heuristic Hazard property under Last Participant Support Extension setting of an application installed in WebSphere?

Comment: Man, I restored your reputation; I hate when one just put with no explained reason a down for a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an article that describes how to set it for a specific application, which is what you asked about,

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014090728

Alternately, to set it on the transaction service, the following can be used,

```
wsadmin>transactionService = AdminConfig.list('TransactionService')
wsadmin>AdminConfig.modify(transactionService, [['acceptHeuristicHazard', 'true']])
''
wsadmin>print AdminConfig.show(transactionService)
[LPSHeuristicCompletion ROLLBACK]
[WSTransactionSpecificationLevel WSTX_10]
[acceptHeuristicHazard true]
[asyncResponseTimeout 30]
[clientInactivityTimeout 60]
[context (cells/Node01Cell/nodes/Node01/servers/server1|server.xml#ApplicationServer_1183122130078)]
[enable true]
[enableFileLocking true]
[enableLoggingForHeuristicReporting false]
[enableProtocolSecurity true]
[heuristicRetryLimit 0]
[heuristicRetryWait 0]
[httpProxyPrefix []]
[httpsProxyPrefix []]
[maximumTransactionTimeout 0]
[properties []]
[propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout 300]
[totalTranLifetimeTimeout 120]
[waitForCommitOutcome false]
[wstxURLPrefixSpecified false]
```